# How do I turn off predictive text in the Gboard on ios?

Tags: keyboard, iphone, ios

I'm on the most recent version of iOS. I use GBoard and I'd like to eliminate the row of words that they offer based on what they think you're trying to type.

There is an option to get rid of emoji suggestions and also auto correction, but I don't see any options to get rid of prediction more generally.

Is that feature available for GBoard?